# How to get beanBuilder instance in doWithSpring

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

Is it possible to access the default beanBuilder instance in Grails from a plugin in `doWithSpring = {}`?

Comment: I provided an answer below to the question as asked but that is a peculiar thing to want to do though.  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31633622/791406), I want to load beans using the same `beanBuilder` instance used in `resources.groovy`, without passing `delegate` from `resources.groovy`; much rather do under the covers from plugin using `doWithSpring()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to `delegate` and that will be an instance of the builder.

Comment: This worked, thank you; only downside is `grailsApplication` does not resolve in custom resource files, resorted to `Holders.getGrailsApplication()` for now (is there a better way?)